# Navigation using osmdroid

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I tried the navigation tutorial using osmdroid api, in which we use RoadManager to make navigate between two points. However what I want to achieve is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEFWO.jpg) (destination is the red marker and current position is the blue marker). If I use the RoadManager class then i am able to get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvWXT.jpg), it just finds the distance using roads, as long as roads are there it finds the distance then the path ends, but we need to be able to route between 2 locations in which the destination would be in sea. So, using osmdroid can we connect 2 markers using a straight line, then route between those 2 points without any restriction of roads,etc as shown in the image link above, so that our current position marker keeps moving as we move until we reach the destination. Also how can we calculate real time distance between the current location and the destination as we travel. Thanks.

Comment: Just draw a line from the last point of the route up to the destination?

Comment: but how would we route from current location to that? like during routing the marker keeps moving and map rotates accordingly, also we get the distance left to cover